# Set theory: union, intersection, subtraction

Tags: elementary-set-theory

As revision for my upcoming test, I'm trying to solve the following question:
$A=\{1,x,x^2\}$
$B=\{|x-1|,x^2-1\}$

a. Calculate $x$ such that $B-A=\{3\}$
My attempt: I tried substituting different values of x to get the set, $B-A=\{3\}$. So, if $x=2$, $A=\{1,2,4\}$ and $B=\{|1|,3\}$. => $B-aA=\{3\}$.
Am I doing this correctly? Is there an algebraic way to solve this question?

b. Calculate $A\cup B$ and $A\cap B$
My attempt: $A\cup B = \{1,x,x^2,|x-1|,x^2-1\}$.
Since there are no identical elements in both sets, $A\cap B = \{\}$
Is my working correct for this question?

c. Calculate $(A-B)-(B-A)$
Please help me with this one.

For the above questions, it is not specified whether I am supposed to use the value of $x$ obtained in part a (which makes more sense to me).

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: b) Take x=0, you'll find identical elements. c) (A-B)-(B-A)=(A-B)

Comment: x=0 gives me A={1,0,0} and B={|-1|,-1}. How do I proceed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For part (a), the difference given has one element, so one element of B equals an element of A. So let's say |x-1| = 1, x or x². The solutions are x = 0 or 2, x = ½ or x = $1/\varphi$ or $-\varphi$ respectively ($\varphi$ is the golden ratio $\frac{\sqrt 5+1}{2}$). The other element of *B* is then -1 or 3, -¾, or $-1/\varphi$ or $\varphi$.

Hold on: we see 3 in there. So let's say x = 2:
$A=\{1, 2, 4\}, B=\{1, 3\}, B-A=\{3\}$. That's the answer! You're correct.

I will assume that the answer to (a) is used for (b) and (c). In that case $A\cup B=\{1, 2, 3, 4\}, A\cap B=\{1\}, A-B=\{2,4\}, (A-B)-(B-A)=\{2,4\}$.

$A-B$ is the set-theoretic difference of two sets, the elements of *A* not in *B*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't get part (a). You stated that 'the difference given has one element, so one element of B equals an element of A'. Doesn't B-A just mean the elements in B that are not in A?

Comment: Why do you assume that the answer to (a) can be used for (b) and (c)?

Comment: Yes, B-A means "elements in B not in A". I was referring to the number of elements in the sets, which for a set S is denoted |S|. |B| = 2, |A| = 3, |B-A| = 1. Obviously |B intersect A| + |B-A| = |B|, so |B intersect A| = 1. One element of B must be equal to one element of A. So I just tried all possible combinations of one element each from A and B to get part (a).

Comment: @EugenCovaci If I do not assume that, then I must solve a whole set of functions depending on which of the five given expressions are equal to each other. The cardinality of each set in question would depend on x. But in the general case, where none of the five numbers are equal, the asker has got part (b) right, and the answer to part (c) is set A itself.

Comment: Take x=0 to see $A \cap B ={1}$

Comment: Ah, I get it now. I used your method to solve this question in a different way: if B-A={3}, 3 must be an element of B. So find all possible combinations of each element of B equal to 3. Thanks again :)